# Use bash variable as array in awk and filter input file by comparing with array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have bash variable like this:

```
val="abc jkl pqr"
```

And I have a file that looks smth like this:

```
abc   4   5
abc   8   8
def   43  4
def   7   51
jkl   4   0
mno   32  2
mno   9   2
pqr   12  1
```

I want to throw away rows from file which first field isn't present in the val:

```
abc   4   5
abc   8   8
jkl   4   0
pqr   12  1
```

My solution in awk doesn't work at all and I don't have any idea why:

```
awk -v var="${val}" 'BEGIN{split(var, arr)}$1 in arr{print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [slice the variable into array indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40848893/1983854):

```
awk -v var="${val}" 'BEGIN{split(var, arr)
                           for (i in arr) 
                               names[arr[i]]
                     }
                     $1 in names' file
```

As commented in the linked question, when you call `split()` you get values for the array, while what you want to set are indexes. The trick is to generate another array with this content.

As you see `$1 in names` suffices, you don't have to call for the action `{print $0}` when this happens, since it is the default.

As a one-liner:

```
$ awk -v var="${val}" 'BEGIN{split(var, arr); for (i in arr) names[arr[i]]} $1 in names' file
abc   4   5
abc   8   8
jkl   4   0
pqr   12  1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Especially for the explanation :^)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E "$( echo "${val}"| sed 's/ /|/g' )" YourFile

# or

awk -v val="${val}" 'BEGIN{gsub(/ /, "|",val)} $1 ~ val' YourFile
```

Grep:

- it use a regex (extended version with option `-E`) that filter all the lines that contains the value. The regex is build OnTheMove in a subshell with a sed that replace the space separator by a `|` meaning *OR*

Awk:

- use the same princip as the grep but everything is made inside (so no subshell)
- use the variable `val` assigned to the shell variable of the same name
- At start of the script (before first line read) change the space, (in *val*) by `|` with `BEGIN{gsub(/ /, "|",val)}`
- than, for every line where first field (default field separator is space/blank in awk, so first is the letter group) matching, print it (defaut action of a filter with `$1 ~ val`.